# cin unintentionally skipping user input

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to write a loop that validates user input, and then repeats if the input is bad. The input must be either a binary number (as a string) or a decimal number (as an int). I have seperate functions to validate this input, but they are not causing any trouble.

The problem arises when I select 1 or 2, and then willingly enter an invalid binary or decimal number. At this point, the do-while loop repeats successfully. The program prints another request for user input to `cout`, But when it comes time for the user to enter input, the program thinks that there is input in the console before I even enter anything. I believe this is a problem with `whitespace/control` characters in the buffer, but I am not sure how to fix it. I have tried using `std::cin >> std::ws` to clear any straggling white space, but no luck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::numeric_limits;
using std::max;
using std::streamsize;
using std::string;



//int toDecimal;

//true is is binary
bool validateBinary(const string &binaryNumber){
    for(int i = 0; i < binaryNumber.length(); i++){
        if((binaryNumber[i] != 1) && (binaryNumber[i] != 0)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
//true if is decimal
bool validateDecimal(){
    return cin;
}

int main() {
    int conversionType = 0; //we initialize conversionType to a default value of 0 to ensure the copiler it will always have a value
    bool isBinary = false;
    bool isDecimal = false;
    string binaryNumberInput;
    int decimalNumberInput;

    do {
        if(conversionType == 0){
        cout << "Enter 1 to convert binary to decimal," << endl;
        cout << "2 to convert decimal to binary, " << endl;
        cout << "or 3 to exit the program: ";
        std::cin >> std::ws; //to clear any whitespace fron cin
        cin >> conversionType; //upon a second iteration, this value is read in before a user input is given
        }

        if(!cin || (conversionType != 1 && conversionType != 2)){
            cout << "Incorrect input." <<  endl;
            cin.clear(); //clear the fail bit
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //used to ignore not-numeric input
        }

        cout << "You have selected option " << conversionType << "." << endl;

        if(conversionType == 1){
            cout << "Please enter a binary number: ";
            cin >> binaryNumberInput;
            isBinary = validateBinary(binaryNumberInput);
            if(!isBinary){
                cout << "The numbered you entered is not a binary number!" << endl;
                conversionType = 0;
            }
        }

        if(conversionType == 2){
            cout << "Please enter a decimal number: ";
            cin >> decimalNumberInput;
            isDecimal = validateDecimal(); //true if succeeded, meaning is a number
            if(!isDecimal){
                cout << "The numbered you entered is not a decimal number!" << endl;
                conversionType = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    while((conversionType != 1 && conversionType != 2) || (isBinary == isDecimal));


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than debug your current program you might want to consider using the standard library to simply things

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
#include <limits>

template<typename T>
void get(T& value)
{
  while (!(std::cin >> value)) {
    std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Enter 1 to convert binary to decimal,\n" <<
               "2 to convert decimal to binary\n";

  int option;

  if (std::cin >> option) {
    switch (option) {
      case 1: {
        std::bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned long long)> bits;
        get(bits); 
        std::cout << bits.to_ullong()  << '\n';
        break;
      }

      case 2: {
        unsigned long long i;
        get(i);
        std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof i>(i) << '\n';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want this to loop you should be able to add it back in again easily enough.

Comment: Thanks but for this assignment we aren't allowed to use any of the conversion functions, or else that would have been my first choice.

Comment: @AdamJ In that case you can still use the general logic above for input error handling. Also next time make it clear what you can and cannot use in the question if it is an assignment.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I am really just looking for an answer as to why my code refuses to read in a value from cin when the loop is repeated. I want to know for my own learning purposes, not just to compete the assignment.

Comment: @AdamJ You need to both reset the error state of `cin` and discard the incorrect input on a failed call to `cin >> decimalNumberInput;` (in that order), otherwise it is immediately passed to `conversionType`.